# script not working on the server but works fine on the localhost

Tags: php, mysql

i have a problem with my script,i made a login script where you enter the username and password and its working perfectly on my localhost(i.e i can login in and out having access to the admin panel) i then uploaded it on my server but the confusing part is that when i try to log in with the right username and password its not accessing the admin panel and showing me the access denied message its like the session is not being set on the server while its perfectly working on my local host.. secondly i created a news page where i can view the news its also showing that there an no posts to show but on the localhost everything is perfectly working
this is my home.php where i enter the username and password

```
<?php

if(isset($_COOKIE['testsite'])){

    header('Location: enter.php');

}else{

echo"
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<center>Please login...</center>


<div align='center'>
<form method='post' action='login.php' id='generalform'>
<table border='1' width='25%'>
<tr><td>Name: </td><td><input type='text' name='name' maxlength='15'/></td></tr><br />
<tr><td>Password: </td><td><input type='password' name='password' maxlength='15'/></td></tr><br />
<tr><td>Remember me?: </td><td><input type='checkbox' name='remember'/></td></tr><br />
</table>
<p>
<input type='submit' value='login' /><p>
</form>
<a href='index.htm'>Back To Main Page</a>
</div>

</body>

</html>";
}
?>
```

and this is enter.php where its being accessed

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['name'])||isset($_COOKIE['testsite'])){

    include('session.php');

}else{

    echo "Access denied!";

}

?>
```

and this is my `news.php` it seems like the squery is not being accessed from the database i reall do not know whats wrong because on the locahost its working perfectly

```
 <?php
include ('connect.php');
$query = "SELECT id, title, author, post, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M %d, %Y') as sd FROM news_posts";
$result = @mysql_query($query);

if ($result) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$url = 'comments.php?id='.$row['id'];
echo '<p><b>'.$row['title'].'</b><br />
'.$row['sd'].'<br />
Posted by : <b>'.$row['author'].'</b><br />
'.$row['post'].'<br />
<a href="javascript:openComments(\''.$url.'\')">Add new comment or view posted comments</a></p>';
}
} else {
echo 'There are no news posts to display';
}
?>
```

this is the login.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_POST){

$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['password'] = md5($_POST['password']);


if($_SESSION['name'] && $_SESSION['password']){

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "nokiae71") or die("problem with connection...");
    mysql_select_db("testsite");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='".$_SESSION['name']."'");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($numrows != 0){

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

            $dbname = $row['name'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password'];

        }
        if($_SESSION['name']==$dbname){
            if($_SESSION['password']==$dbpassword){

                if(($_POST['remember']) == 'on'){
                    $expire = time()+86400;
                    setcookie('testsite', $_POST['name'], $expire);
                }
                header("location:enter.php");

            }else{
                echo "Your password is incorrect!";
            }

        }else{
            echo "Your name is incorrect!";
        }

    }else{
        echo "This name is not registered!";    
    }

}else{
    echo "You have to type a name and password!";
}
}else{

echo "Access denied!";
exit;
}
?>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: if you access you can check if the session files are actully be crated

Comment: @Mihai i just added it

Comment: Are you still trying to connect to localhost from the server version?

Comment: no im trying to use it on the server i uploaded it online but i can not get access when its online

Comment: do you updated the database on the server? Usually I forget about that part, on small projects.

Comment: Is the database connection information on the live server right? I noticed in news.php you use the @ to suppress the error in the connection. $result = @mysql_query($query); If you remove the @, does it throw a connection error?

Comment: @AcelasiEu i updated my database its like the the first problem is coming from the enter.php because thats where the access denied is coming from from,the session is not being set and it can not include the file session.php i do not know why

Comment: If you think the problem is in session.php i'd suggest working your way through that printing out the key parts to make sure they look right. I'd print out the $_POST'ed name and password, then the query you are executing to pull the user info, and then i'd check if the conditional "if" statements were being matched like they should.